# Looping an RDD to create Graphs in Spark with Scala

Tags: rdd, spark-graphx

Trying to loop through and RDD and create Graphs using the data on each record.
The code is like this:

bigjoin has the structure `RDD[(String, List[(Long, Long)])]`

```
bigjoin.foreach( a => {
      val imsi = a._1
      val pairs = a._2
      val lsrgraph = Graph.fromEdgeTuples(pairs, defaultValue = "missing")
      // do something else with graph
    })
```

My problem is that Graph.fromEdgeTuples requires an `RDD[(graphx.VertexId, graphx.VertexId)]` instead... cannot figure out how to make the `List[(Long, Long)]` to become an `RDD[(Long, Long)]` to execute that line. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

found an alternative

`val bigjoin3 = bigjoin.map(x => Edge(x._2(0),x._2(1),x._1) )
 val mygraph = Graph.fromEdges(bigjoin3, defaultValue = "ignore")`

the graph will have all the nodes and the edges the original index as a property.